# Filtering out data frame rows by partial string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to `pandas`, and I'm trying to create a data frame by pulling partial strings from one of the columns of the original

```
recipe_info = {
    'title' = [ 'waffles', 'eggs', 'chocolate pancakes', 'pancakes']
    'rating' = [ 3.4, 2.8, 3,6, 1.5 ]

my_recipes = pd.DataFrame(recipe_info)

recipe_info[recipe_info['title'].str.contains("pancake")]
```

**desired output:**

```
all_the_pancakes = {
     'title' = ['chocolate pancakes', 'pancakes']
     'rating' = [3.6, 1.5]
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Refer [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is your input and desired output?

Comment: to create an example take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
recipe_info = {
    'title': [ 'waffles', 'eggs', 'chocolate pancakes', 'pancakes'],
    'rating': [ 3.4, 2.8, 3.6, 1.5 ]}


my_recipes = pd.DataFrame(recipe_info)

new_df = my_recipes[my_recipes['title'].str.contains('pancakes')]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   rating               title                                                                                                         
2     3.6  chocolate pancakes                                                                                                         
3     1.5            pancakes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can also use [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
new_df =df.set_index('title').filter(like='pancakes', axis = 0).reset_index()
```